# Can I set up something to monitor Cron JOb/script

Tags: linux, bash, monit

Can I set up something to monitor Cron Job, a script running and if it fails it should restart the script and alert us? for the failure it may have to check the logs for keywords?

Comment: Jobs in k8s automatically retry on failure. If you fix your job to return a non-zero exit code when it fails, the behavior you are asking for will happen by default.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Are you using the monit tag because you actually use monit, or did that just autocomplete? (If you don't use monit, I would suggest replacing your cron job with a systemd timer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a cron job you can use a similar function in monit and evaluate the return code. The monit will send a mail if the status fail.
For some additional information see https://www.mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#SERVICE-POLL-TIME

The monit program can not monitor the executed cron jobs. If error messages are written to a log file monit can use the messages to send a mail.